# Stretch a part of a picture, not the whole (9patch)

Tags: android, image-processing, nine-patch

Here is the problem : 
[image: irregular size of the pictures making it ugly]

As you can see the black chronological line is messed up, more or less stretched.

I actually tried 9patching, but honestly I don't get the whole thing.

Is it actually possible to solve my problem ? If yes, can 9patching the picture do the job ? If yes, how ?

As an extra, I give you the xml of each rows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/point"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Test 1 :

[image]

Test 2 :

With this picture :

[image]

I get this result :
[image]

Test 3 :
[image]

Comment: Can you share the 9-patch you have tried?

Comment: Edited with the picture. I actually tried some other, with surprising but not satisfying results... That one is the one used for the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes it's possible by using a 9 patch.
2. Your 9-patch file is wrong. You have inverted the stretchable area, meaning at the moment, the circle will be stretched, and not the other parts.

   Just draw the vertical border where you want the image to be stretched, which are the areas below and above the circle in your case.

   Also remove the horizontal line as I guess you don't want the image's width to be stretched.

You might find [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) documentation page interesting.

EDIT: I just quickly tried what I explained, and it worked using this 9-patch:

[image]

Please note the circle is not 100% centered, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Edited trying your suggestion

Comment: Not working with me. Edited result on original post.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Simple Nine-patch Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html). You load an image, you specify the area that can be stretched, and he automatically generates nine-patch graphics (xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi) to download as a zip package.

Comment: Cool tool. Still stuck with the problem.

Comment: Try stretching from one side only (the circle won't be in the middle). If all else fails use 2 pictures one as a rectangle and the other as a circle and align the circle to be centered vertically on top of the rectangle.